# Scipy: Calculation of standardized euclidean via cdist

Tags: python, scipy

The formula is available in the docs and pointed to in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31735609/3656081). However when I'm trying to apply it I'm not getting a matching answer. I'm sure there's some silly mistake I'm making somewhere so thanks for bearing with me:

---

**Setup**

Say I have 2 matrices:

```
X: array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
X2: array([[1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 0]])
```

Now applying `Xans = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(X, X2, 'seuclidean')` gives:

```
Xans: array([[2.23606798, 2.88675135, 3.16227766],
       [1.82574186, 0.        , 2.88675135]])
```

Let's just focus on `Xans[0][0] = 2.23606798`, which should have been obtained by applying `seuclidean(X[0], X2[0])`.

---

**Method 1: Using pdist**

I tried doing this via `pdist` but get a NaN:

```
In [104]: scipy.spatial.distance.pdist([X[0], X2[0]], metric='seuclidean')
Out[104]: array([nan])
```

Why is this happening?

---

**Method 2: Direct Formula Application**

I tried manually using the formula linked in the answer above as follows:

```
In [107]: (((X[0] - X2[0])**2).sum()/(np.var([X[0], X2[0]])))**0.5
Out[107]: 2.0
```

As can be seen this is giving 2.0?

I'm clearly doing something very wrong - What is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *standardized Euclidean distance* weights *each variable* with a separate variance.  If you don't provide the variances with the `V` argument, it computes them from the input array.  This is mentioned in the [`pdist` docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) in the "Parameters" section under `**kwargs`, where it shows:

```
V : ndarray
The variance vector for standardized Euclidean.
Default: var(X, axis=0, ddof=1)
```

For example:

```
In [39]: A
Out[39]: 
array([[3, 0, 2],
       [2, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [3, 1, 2],
       [1, 0, 0]])

In [40]: from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

In [41]: pdist(A, metric='seuclidean')
Out[41]: 
array([ 1.98029509,  2.55814731,  1.82574186,  2.71163072,  2.63368079,
        0.76696499,  2.9868995 ,  3.14284123,  1.35581536,  3.26898677])
```

We get the same result if we provide the variances computed as explained in the docstring:

```
In [42]: pdist(A, metric='seuclidean', V=np.var(A, axis=0, ddof=1))
Out[42]: 
array([ 1.98029509,  2.55814731,  1.82574186,  2.71163072,  2.63368079,
        0.76696499,  2.9868995 ,  3.14284123,  1.35581536,  3.26898677])
```

Of course, if you provide variances that are all 1, you get the regular Euclidean distance:

```
In [43]: pdist(A, metric='seuclidean', V=np.ones(A.shape[1]))
Out[43]: 
array([ 1.41421356,  3.16227766,  1.        ,  2.82842712,  2.44948974,
        1.        ,  2.44948974,  3.31662479,  1.41421356,  3.        ])

In [44]: pdist(A, metric='euclidean')
Out[44]: 
array([ 1.41421356,  3.16227766,  1.        ,  2.82842712,  2.44948974,
        1.        ,  2.44948974,  3.31662479,  1.41421356,  3.        ])
```

The problem with your "Method 1" is that in your input array of just two points (i.e. `[X[0], X2[0]]`), the second and third components of the points don't change, so the variance associated with those components is 0:

```
In [45]: p = np.array([X[0], X2[0]])

In [46]: p
Out[46]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0]])

In [47]: np.var(p, axis=0, ddof=1)
Out[47]: array([ 0.5,  0. ,  0. ])
```

When the code for the `seuclidean` divides by these variances, the result is either infinity or NaN--the latter if the numerator is also 0, which is the case in the third component of the input `[X[0], X2[0]]`.

To work around this, you have to decide how you want to handle the case where the variance of a component is 0, and handle it explicitly.  For example, if you want it to act like that variance is 1 in that case (just to avoid dividing by 0) you could do something like the following.

Suppose `B` is our array of points.  The third column of `B` is all 1s.

```
In [63]: B
Out[63]: 
array([[3, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [3, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```

Compute the variances of the columns:

```
In [64]: V = np.var(B, axis=0, ddof=1)

In [65]: V
Out[65]: array([ 1.7,  0.3,  0. ])
```

Replace the variances that are 0 with 1:

```
In [66]: V[V == 0] = 1

In [67]: V
Out[67]: array([ 1.7,  0.3,  1. ])
```

Use `V` to compute the standardized Euclidean distances:

```
In [68]: pdist(B, metric='seuclidean', V=V)
Out[68]: 
array([ 1.98029509,  2.30089497,  1.82574186,  1.53392998,  2.38459106,
        0.76696499,  1.98029509,  2.93725228,  0.76696499,  2.38459106])
```

This has the same effect as simply removing the constant column:

```
In [69]: pdist(B[:, :2], metric='seuclidean')
Out[69]: 
array([ 1.98029509,  2.30089497,  1.82574186,  1.53392998,  2.38459106,
        0.76696499,  1.98029509,  2.93725228,  0.76696499,  2.38459106])
```

---

Your "Method 2" is wrong because your formula is wrong.  You have to keep the variances for each component.  `np.var([X[0], X2[0]])` computes the (single) variance of all the values in the input.  Instead, you need to use the `axis` and `ddof` arguments shown above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!